# Linear combination of sine and cosine

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis

I was explaining to my students the other day why $\cos(2x)$ is not a linear combination of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Besides the canonical method of using special values of sine and cosine, I noticed something interesting. In the following, all vector spaces are over $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider the linear space $C^\infty_b(\mathbb{R})$ of real-valued bounded smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$, and take any $c > 0$. We say a function $f \in C^\infty_b(\mathbb{R})$ has property $P(c)$, if for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (including $0$), we have
$$\sup f^{(k+1)} = c \sup f^{(k)} = -\inf f^{(k+1)} = -c \inf f^{(k)}.$$
Here, the supremum and infimum are of course taken over $\mathbb{R}$, and $f^{(k)}$ is the $k$-th derivative of $f$, with the convention that $f^{(0)}=f$.

Define
$$S(c) = \{f \in C^\infty_b(\mathbb{R}) \,\vert\, f \text{ has property } P(c)\}.$$
Since for fixed $a,b$ and all $x$, we have $a \sin(x) + b \cos(x) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \sin(x + \theta) $ for some fixed $\theta$, it is clear that all linear combinations of $\sin(cx)$ and $\cos(cx)$ belong to $S(c)$. In particular, linear combinations of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are all in $S(1)$, while $\cos(2x)$ is not.

**Question:** is it true that $S(c) = \operatorname{Vect}\bigl(\sin(cx), \cos(cx)\bigr)$?

If $f \in S(1)$ and $f$ is periodic, then using Fourier series, I can prove that $f$ is indeed $2 \pi$-periodic and $f \in \operatorname{Vect}\bigl(\sin(x), \cos(x)\bigr)$ with some work. Although I haven't checked this yet, I also believe that the periodic case for $S(c)$ where $c>0$ is arbitrary could be established by a more elaborate Fourier series argument (of course, I could be wrong). So the real interest lies in treating the non-periodic case, i.e., answering the following

**Special case:** does $f \in S(c)$ imply $f$ is periodic?

At first, I suspect the answer to the above special case is negative. But after some experiment, I am not so sure. Note that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series (say around $0$) for all $f \in S(c)$ is infinite, so the Taylor series of $f$ converges to $f$ itself. In particular, all functions in $S(c)$ are automatically analytic, so one does not have much freedom when trying to construct a (counter-)example.

If the answer turns out to be negative, then can one at least assert that $S(c)$ is a linear subspace? What if we only consider periodic functions for some fixed period in case $S(c)$ is not a linear subspace? Of course, these probably depend on the explicit form of the answer which is not yet known to me, and all of these are just some (perhaps stupid and naive) speculation on an old exercise of a first-year undergraduate. But it seems interesting, and any thought is appreciated.

**Edit**: I was a bit careless in formulating the question since the questions for all different $c$ are equivalent merely by rescaling, so one can simply assume $c = 1$, in which case we still have much work to do.

**Edit 2**: Proof of the periodic case can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vyp5bcaGVXHvdxuvksNaaXQcrNlG4pFT/view?usp=sharing) in case anyone is interested.

Comment: Could you modulate $\sin(x)$ by some sufficiently smooth bump function $\varphi(x)$ with $\varphi(x)\to 1$ as $x\to\infty$? At first glance that seems like it should work, and since you're in $C^\infty$, I would think that the usual bumps are sufficient for this...

Comment: All such functions are analytic, so once it vanishes on some interval, it is zero everywhere. There's unfortunately no analytic bump functions!

Comment: @RickSternbach I didn't pay sufficient attention to the notes about analyticity later in the post! That said, it seems like one could still modulate by a Gaussian, something along the lines of $\phi(x)=1-e^{-x^2}$...

Comment: Why should those functions be analytic? Even if a Taylor series converges, that does not mean that it converges to the function.

Comment: @Zero Just consider the remainder of the Taylor expansion to the order $n$, and you will see immediately that due to the restrictions of the higher derivatives, the remainder tends to zero as $n$ goes to infinity, which means exactly that the Taylor series converges pointwise to the function itself and the function is indeed given by a power series (its Taylor series).

Comment: @HuaWang : Can you let us know how you dealt with periodic $f$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I will only treat the case $S(1)$, the general case follows by rescaling as remarked in the edit. Basically there are two steps. 1. One shows that such $f$ must be a trigonometric polynomial. More precisely, using integral par parts repeatedly, and by the restrictions on the higher derivatives, one shows that the Fourier coefficients vanishes once the order is high enough. 2. Now that $f$ is a trigonometric polynomial, taking the derivative repeatedly, one shows that all supremum and infimum involved are exactly determined by the coefficients of highest order, the rest follows.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Sorry I couldn't be clearer due to the restrictions of characters in the comment. I could elaborate on each of the above step if needed. But I believe with some work, one can finish the periodic case using this rough outline.

Comment: @HuaWang : You wrote in your post: "If $f \in S(1)$ and $f$ is periodic, then using Fourier series, I can prove that $f$ is indeed $2 \pi$-periodic and $f \in \operatorname{Vect}\bigl(\sin(x), \cos(x)\bigr)$ with some work." If can indeed prove this, I think it could well be useful for some of us to see that proof, which you could write elsewhere, and here provide a link to that proof.

Comment: @IosifPinelis OK. Following your advice, I wrote a detailed version of the periodic case, and put it on my google drive. Here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vyp5bcaGVXHvdxuvksNaaXQcrNlG4pFT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @IosifPinelis And as one can see now, the periodic case is really just an exercise of Fourier series (albeit a nice one imho), and I am more interested in treating the non-periodic case...

Comment: @HuaWang : Thank you for your write-up for the periodic case. Yes, it is nice (I think there is a typo in the first display on p. 4, though). It seems that you use the periodicity very essentially. I hoped a Paley--Wiener theorem (which corresponds to the first part of your proof, before Lemma 2) together with what you did in the periodic case could be close to sufficient, but now I see you use some pretty delicate arithmetic, seemingly not available in the non-periodic case. I wish someone solves your problem, which could be a good learning experience for interested users.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thanks for pointing out this typo. I will fix it when I get home (I was stupid enough to include only the pdf in my google drive, not the tex file, which is only available in my home computer). Concerning the general case, I was thinking that one might begin with the property that $f^{(4)}$ should be $f$ itself (or $f^{(2)}=-f$) for such functions, but couldn't proceed further.

Comment: I have only some comments. First of all, expanding $f(x+iy)$ in power series around $x$ one sees that it is bounded by $e^{|y|}$ hence, using Paley-Wiener, its Fourier transform, as a tempered distribution, has support in the interval $[-1,1]$. To conclude we should exclude the interior but this uses only $|f^{(n)}| \le 1$ for all n. Using Ascoli-Arzela' and the identity $\hat{f^{(k)}}(\xi)=(i\xi)^k\hat{f}(\xi)$ one (probably) can show that $f^{(4k)}$ converges uniformly on compact sets to $g$ and $g^4=g$...but then maybe some body else sees how to go on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted by the OP we can replace $f$ by $af(bx)$ for suitable $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ so that wlog we can take $c=1$ and ensure that $\sup f=-\inf f=1$.

Firstly we note that $f(z)$ is infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ so we can form the taylor series at 0, $f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(i)}(0)}{i!}z^i$. Since $|f^{(i)}(0)|\leq 1$ for all $i\geq 0$ we have  $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|\frac{f^{(i)}(0)}{i!}z^i|=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{|f^{(i)}(0)|}{i!}|z|^i\leq \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{|z|^i}{i!}$ which converges for all $z$ to $e^{|z|}$.

Hence $F(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{i!}z^i$ is an absolutely convergent series defining an entire function on $\mathbb{C}$ agreeing with $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\sup f^{(k)}=-\inf f^{(k)}=1$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ and $|F(z)|\leq e^{|z|}$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

**We now determine the form of $F$ given the preceding conditions.**

First note that Bernstein proved the following (see Rahman and Tariq$^1$) as an extension of his related inequality for polynomials:

**Theorem** Let $g$ be an entire function of exponential type $\tau>0$ such that $|g(x)|\leq M$ on the real axis. Then $$\sup_{-\infty<x<+\infty}|g^{'}(x)|\leq M\tau.$$

Now $|F(z)|\leq e^{|z|}$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and therefore we know that $F$ is of exponential type 1. In addition $|F(x)|=|f(x)|\leq 1$ on the real axis.

**We are therefore interested in the conditions of equality in the above.**

Fortunately in their book "Analytic Theory of Polynomials"$^2$  Rahman and Schmeisser prove (Theorem 14.1.7) that equality holds in the above if and only if $g(z)=ae^{i\tau z}+be^{-i\tau z}$ where $|a|+|b|=M$. (You can access the relevant pages 513-514 on [google books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FzFEEVO3PXYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=analytic%20theory%20of%20polynomials%20rahman%20pdf&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIvM7clvLnAhUTbcAKHREQDRwQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=analytic%20theory%20of%20polynomials%20rahman%20pdf&f=false))

$|F(x)|\leq 1$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and hence in the above theorem we may take $M=1$, $\tau=1$ and $g=F$ since $|F|$ is of exponential type 1. Also $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|F^{'}(x)|=1$ which means we have the case of equality.

Thus $F(z)=ae^{iz}+be^{-iz}$ where $|a|+|b|=M=1$.

On the real axis $F$ is real valued and agrees with $f$ so we must have $f(x)=ae^{ix}+be^{-ix}$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a=\bar{b}$. Setting $a=c+id$ we obtain $f(x)=2c\cos x-2d\sin x$ with $|a|=|b|=2\sqrt{c^2+d^2}=1$. Rewriting with $C=2c$, $D=-2d$, we obtain

$$f(x)=C\cos x+D\sin x$$
for some constants $C,D\in \mathbb{R}$, $C^2+D^2=1$.

This proves the OP's conjecture. Note that the condition $C^2+D^2=1$ is due to the bound we imposed on $f$ due to our normalisation which is not part of the definition of $S(c)$.

<sub>**1** *Rahman, Q. I.; Tariq, Q. M.*, [**On Bernstein’s inequality for entire functions of exponential type**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2009.05.035), J. Math. Anal. Appl. 359, No. 1, 168-180 (2009). [ZBL1168.30002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1168.30002).</sub>

<sub>**2** *Rahman, Q. I.; Schmeisser, G.*, Analytic theory of polynomials, London Mathematical Society Monographs. New Series 26. Oxford: Oxford University Press (ISBN 0-19-853493-0/hbk). xiv, 742 p. (2002). [ZBL1072.30006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1072.30006).</sub>

Comment: Reading your solution, it looks as if the condition $\inf = -\sup$ is actually superfluous and the result follows only from the conditions $\sup \vert f^{(k)} \vert = 1$ for all $k \ge 0$. So, you did prove a stronger result (unless I have overlooked something).

Comment: @LucGuyot I think you can lose all the sup and inf conditions except one of them say $\sup |f^{(i)}|=1$ or $\inf|f^{(i)}|=-1$, $i>0$ as long as you have $|f^{(k)}|\leq1$ for all $k\geq 1$. You need the bounds on the derivatives to get the $|F(z)|\leq e^{|z|}$ so that $F$ has exponential type 1, essential for this solution.

Comment: @LucGuyot Note that if you have $\sup |f^{(i)}|=1$ or $\inf|f^{(i)}|=-1$, $i>0$ then you just apply the same method to $f^{(i-1)}$ to get the result.